# How can I make sure an app registers with Mountain Lion's Notification Center?

Tags: macos, dropbox, osx-mountain-lion, growl

I own two Macs with an identical set of apps that both have the latest version of Mountain Lion (10.8.2). On one Mac, many of these apps register with Notification Center (NC). On the other, many do not. They just use Growl instead.

For example, Dropbox on Mac 1 is in NC. But on Mac 2, Dropbox is only in Growl. It will not show up in NC. Mac 1 also has Growl, but the apps "know" to register with NC as well.

I've tried reinstalling Dropbox after completely wiping its associated hidden files and it's still only registering with Growl and not NC. I'm also using the latest version of Growl.

Because Apple's NC implementation is a very closed system, I can't go in there and manually add Dropbox to the list or configure anything else. So I don't know what to do anymore...

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, Dropbox has never released Notification Center support in the official releases. They have only been [released](https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes) in the [experimental builds](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=65893).

You might have inadvertently installed an experimental build on Mac 1 but only the official release on Mac 2?

Comment: Besides Dropbox there's a few other apps that also exhibit the same problem: registering with NC on Mac 1, but not on Mac 2. So it's not just Dropbox, and Dropbox has had official NC support in official builds for a few months now.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem myself. Follow these steps:

1. Uninstall Growl
2. Uninstall any apps that have not registered with Notification Center (but should)
3. Reboot your Mac
4. Reinstall the apps you uninstalled earlier
5. Go to System Preferences --> Notification Center and check the lefthand column to see if the reinstalled apps are in the list
6. Reinstall Growl

That should solve it!